# The below hashTable program is not working?

Tags: java

I am new to java and learning things now, I have tried the below program to store key value pairs in hash table. I can add a key and value and able to retrieve it.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Hashtable balance= new Hashtable();
    Enumeration names;
    String str;
    int a;

    balance.put("vishnu",new Integer(1000));
    balance.put("Sam",new Integer(1420));
    balance.put("Gobi",new Integer(890));
    balance.put("Vel",new Integer(50));

    names=balance.keys();
    while(names.hasMoreElements()){
        str=(String) names.nextElement();
        System.out.println(str + " is getting "+balance.get(str));
    }
    System.out.println();
```

But, when i tried to modify the added value. This gives me a null pointer exception.

```
    a=((Integer) balance.get("vel")).intValue();
    System.out.println("Before Adding "+a);

    balance.put("Vel", new Integer(a+1000));

    System.out.println("After adding "+balance.get("vel"));

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vel` is different from `Vel`in terms of hashtable keys. You have inserted `vel` in the hashtable and not `Vel`

Answer (score 0):

```
a=((Integer) balance.get("vel")).intValue();
```

following condition evaluates to false

```
"vel".equals("Vel")
```

Answer (score 0):

the key with which you are trying to retrieve your value is incorrect. there is a typo in what you are trying to do. 
you are entering the key `"Vel"` in your hashtable but are trying to retrieve `"vel".` 
There is no key value pair with `"vel"` as the key.

This below statement

```
a=((Integer) balance.get("vel")).intValue();
```

should be this

```
a=((Integer) balance.get("Vel")).intValue();
```